# 404 error on Spring Boot 3.0.2 and springdoc v2

Tags: java, spring-boot, springdoc

I have the following springbootframework version:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

and I have declared the dependency as the web sais (https://springdoc.org/v2/)

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I go to: http://localhost:8080/index.html I get error 404.
I do not have any additional config. I don't have any context path overriden on application properties. What do you think I may be missing?

Using Java 17 (.jdks\corretto-17.0.6\bin\java.exe)
According to https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/releases spring doc 2.1.0 should be compatible with spring-boot-starter-parent with 3.0.2

Comment: could you provide more info about the project? how you coded the startup, any error message showed in the logs? maybe this article about [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) could help

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Not only the dependency `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` is needed. As I had Webflux as dependency I needed to add:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

And if validation probles appear, make sure you have

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```